# Serialization of child models

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have models:

```
class CommonEditor(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Common Atributes Mask'


class Color(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    editor = models.ForeignKey(CommonEditor, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
```

So I make serialization this way:

```
class ColorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Color
        fields = '__all__'

class CommonAttributesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    color = ColorSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CommonEditor
        fields = ('pk', 'color')
```

And then view:

```
class CommonAttributeAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CommonAttributesSerializer
    queryset = CommonEditor.objects.all()
```

I get only pk of my CommonEditor Model. Why can't i get the full Atributes Mask and how can I fix it? Big thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default name for reverse foreign key relation is `modelname_set` or in your case `color_set`. So try to rename `color` field to `color_set`:

```
class CommonAttributesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    color_set = ColorSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CommonEditor
        fields = ('pk', 'color_set')
```

Answer (score 1):

The `CommonAttributesSerializer` search for a **`color`** attribute in **CommonEditor**'s instance, but it couldn't find. In DRF serializer, a parameter called `source` will says explicitly where to look for the data. So , change the serializer as below:

```
class CommonAttributesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    color = ColorSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, <b>source='color_set'</b>)

    class Meta:
        model = CommonEditor
        fields = ('pk', 'color')
```

Reference : [**DRF Fields -`source`**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source)

Answer (score 1):

This can also be achieved via `SerializerMethodField` and can be seen as follow:

```
class CommonAttributesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    color = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = CommonEditor
        fields = ('pk', 'color')

    def get_color(self, common_editor):
        return ColorSerializer(common_editor.color_set.all(), many=True).data
```

Documentation: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield